# How to parse a nested JSON object in android

Tags: android, json, pojo

I receive below JSON data in this format from my API using Retrofit:

```
{
    "id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
    "name": "Salon Ultra",
    "lat": 0.36992,
    "lng": 32.668261,
    "address": "Level 3, Garden City",
    "opening_time": "09:00:00",
    "closing_time": "20:00:00",
    "rating": 4,
    "whatsapp_contact": "+256701882716",
    "primary_contact": "09:00:00",
    "secondary_contact": "09:00:00",
    "img_url": "hair.jpg",
    "services": [
        {
            "service_id": "1e3b47f5-f915-410d-9a76-a018e83ff4b1",
            "service_name": "Classic Locs",
            "service_price": "150000",
            "s_img_url": "img_locs.jpg",
            "s_service_provider_id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
            "s_reviews_count": null,
            "s_service_category_id": 1,
            "updated_at": "2020-10-03 15:13:08",
            "created_at": "2020-10-03 15:13:08"
        },
        {
            "service_id": "2f384780-110f-4307-b1de-f4070bce2da9",
            "service_name": "Straightened Natural",
            "service_price": "20000",
            "s_img_url": "img_natural_straight.jpg",
            "s_service_provider_id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
            "s_reviews_count": null,
            "s_service_category_id": 1,
            "updated_at": "2020-10-03 15:13:54",
            "created_at": "2020-10-03 15:13:54"
        },
        {
            "service_id": "31fbfb23-60ba-4704-9e6a-19047bdb0a14",
            "service_name": "Crochet Mid Length",
            "service_price": "120000",
            "s_img_url": "img_crochet.jpg",
            "s_service_provider_id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
            "s_reviews_count": null,
            "s_service_category_id": 1,
            "updated_at": "2020-09-25 21:39:20",
            "created_at": "2020-09-25 21:30:49"
        },
        {
            "service_id": "b8a288ec-338d-4472-945e-60bb9ee7e7bd",
            "service_name": "Mid-length Bob",
            "service_price": "60000",
            "s_img_url": "img_bob.jpg",
            "s_service_provider_id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
            "s_reviews_count": null,
            "s_service_category_id": 1,
            "updated_at": "2020-10-03 15:11:53",
            "created_at": "2020-10-03 15:11:53"
        },
        {
            "service_id": "c8dec22a-2cd4-43e5-9664-64bf7364cd8a",
            "service_name": "Wild Goddess Weave",
            "service_price": "70000",
            "s_img_url": "img_wild.jpg",
            "s_service_provider_id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
            "s_reviews_count": null,
            "s_service_category_id": 1,
            "updated_at": "2020-10-03 15:13:26",
            "created_at": "2020-10-03 15:13:26"
        }
    ],
    "categories": [
        {
            "service_category_id": 1,
            "parent_service_category_id": null,
            "sc_name": "Hair",
            "sc_img_url": "hair.jpg",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-24 20:21:50",
            "created_at": "2020-09-24 20:21:50",
            "pivot": {
                "service_provider_id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
                "service_category_id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "service_category_id": 3,
            "parent_service_category_id": null,
            "sc_name": "Hair Products",
            "sc_img_url": "hair-products.jpg",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-24 20:21:50",
            "created_at": "2020-09-24 20:21:50",
            "pivot": {
                "service_provider_id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
                "service_category_id": 3
            }
        }
    ],
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id": "08e2c93e-60b9-4cb6-be7c-ff3e7cbf3bce",
            "product_name": "Cantu Hair Conditioner",
            "product_old_price": null,
            "product_price": "32000",
            "p_img_url": "img_conditioner.jpg",
            "p_reviews_count": null,
            "p_service_provider_id": "8dfa4c16-60d7-43ed-9292-21f12a4b7f48",
            "p_service_category_id": 1,
            "updated_at": "2020-09-25 21:10:56",
            "created_at": "2020-09-25 21:03:23"
        }
    ],
    "reviews": []
}
```

I have used [JSON Schema to POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate my Model class, which is as follows:

```
public class ServiceProviderResponse {

        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private String id;
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        private String name;
        @SerializedName("lat")
        @Expose
        private Double lat;
        @SerializedName("lng")
        @Expose
        private Double lng;
        @SerializedName("address")
        @Expose
        private String address;
        @SerializedName("opening_time")
        @Expose
        private String openingTime;
        @SerializedName("closing_time")
        @Expose
        private String closingTime;
        @SerializedName("rating")
        @Expose
        private Integer rating;
        @SerializedName("whatsapp_contact")
        @Expose
        private String whatsappContact;
        @SerializedName("primary_contact")
        @Expose
        private String primaryContact;
        @SerializedName("secondary_contact")
        @Expose
        private String secondaryContact;
        @SerializedName("img_url")
        @Expose
        private String imgUrl;
        @SerializedName("services")
        @Expose
        private List<Service> services;
        @SerializedName("categories")
        @Expose
        private List<ServiceCategory> categories;
        @SerializedName("products")
        @Expose
        private List<Product> products;
        @SerializedName("reviews")
        @Expose
        private List<ServiceProviderReview> reviews;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Double getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(Double lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

        public Double getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(Double lng) {
            this.lng = lng;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public String getOpeningTime() {
            return openingTime;
        }

        public void setOpeningTime(String openingTime) {
            this.openingTime = openingTime;
        }

        public String getClosingTime() {
            return closingTime;
        }

        public void setClosingTime(String closingTime) {
            this.closingTime = closingTime;
        }

        public Integer getRating() {
            return rating;
        }

        public void setRating(Integer rating) {
            this.rating = rating;
        }

        public String getWhatsappContact() {
            return whatsappContact;
        }

        public void setWhatsappContact(String whatsappContact) {
            this.whatsappContact = whatsappContact;
        }

        public String getPrimaryContact() {
            return primaryContact;
        }

        public void setPrimaryContact(String primaryContact) {
            this.primaryContact = primaryContact;
        }

        public String getSecondaryContact() {
            return secondaryContact;
        }

        public void setSecondaryContact(String secondaryContact) {
            this.secondaryContact = secondaryContact;
        }

        public String getImgUrl() {
            return imgUrl;
        }

        public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
            this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        }

        public List<Service> getServices() {
            return services;
        }

        public void setServices(List<Service> services) {
            this.services = services;
        }

        public List<ServiceCategory> getCategories() {
            return categories;
        }

        public void setCategories(List<ServiceCategory> categories) {
            this.categories = categories;
        }

        public List<Product> getProducts() {
            return products;
        }

        public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
            this.products = products;
        }

        public List<ServiceProviderReview> getReviews() {
            return reviews;
        }

        public void setReviews(List<ServiceProviderReview> reviews) {
            this.reviews = reviews;
        }

}
```

Example of model for the child lists:

```
public class ServiceCategory {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("parent_id")
    @Expose
    private int parent_id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("img_url")
    @Expose
    private String img_url;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getParent_id() {
        return parent_id;
    }

    public void setParent_id(int parent_id) {
        this.parent_id = parent_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImg_url() {
        return img_url;
    }

    public void setImg_url(String img_url) {
        this.img_url = img_url;
    }
}
```

In my fragment, below line works:

```
binding.setProvider(data);
```

The details of the provider are populated correctly.

However, I have failed to use getters for the data from the nested lists in the data, even though I can get the size of the list and loop through its items. Recycler views also do not populate.

```
//Chip view creates two blank chips
List<ServiceCategory> categories = data.getCategories();

        for(int i = 0; i<categories.size(); i++){
            ServiceCategory category = categories.get(i);
            Chip chip = new Chip(activity);
            chip.setText(category.getName());
            chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.colorPrimary);;
            chip.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite, activity.getTheme()));
            chip.setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextAppearance);
            categoryChipGroup.addView(chip);
        }
```

Comment: can i see, what the Log if you write this in your loop block:
  
```ServiceCategory category = categories.get(i);   
Log.w("DATA", "THIS DATA : " + category.getName());```

Comment: I get a null pointer exception saying println needs a message

Answer (score 0):

Your deserializing the **ServiceCategory** wrong.

Replace your **ServiceCategory** class with the following code:

```
    public class ServiceCategory {
    @SerializedName("service_category_id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("parent_service_category_id")
    @Expose
    private int parentId;
    @SerializedName("sc_name")
    @Expose
    private String scName;
    @SerializedName("sc_img_url")
    @Expose
    private String scImageUrl;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("pivot")
    @Expose
    private Pivot pivot;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(int parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public String getScName() {
        return scName;
    }

    public void setScName(String scName) {
        this.scName = scName;
    }

    public String getScImageUrl() {
        return scImageUrl;
    }

    public void setScImageUrl(String scImageUrl) {
        this.scImageUrl = scImageUrl;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Pivot getPivot() {
        return pivot;
    }

    public void setPivot(Pivot pivot) {
        this.pivot = pivot;
    }

    public class Pivot {
        @SerializedName("service_provider_id")
        @Expose
        private String providerID;
        @SerializedName("service_category_id")
        @Expose
        private String serviceCategoryID;

        public String getProviderID() {
            return providerID;
        }

        public void setProviderID(String providerID) {
            this.providerID = providerID;
        }

        public String getServiceCategoryID() {
            return serviceCategoryID;
        }

        public void setServiceCategoryID(String serviceCategoryID) {
            this.serviceCategoryID = serviceCategoryID;
        }
    }
}
```